# How to resize Image component in Next.js by height

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I receive from the server three images with different size ratios and I want to resize them by height. I am using the Image component from next.js and it is on a container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    <div style={{position:"relative", height:50, width:100}}>
             <Image
                src="/image.png" 
                layout="fill"
                objectFit="contain"
              />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the height directly in the Image component:

```
<Image
  src="/your_image"
  alt="image"
  height={200}
/>
```